# I want to display the picklist value in different column according to their stage like Completed should display in one column and rest in other

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, visualforce-component

[image]VF page:

```
<apex:page StandardController="QuickCase__c" extensions="quicksls" action="{!init}">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:outputPanel id="dynamicTablePanel">
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="dynamicTable" value="{!QuickCase__c}" var="qs"
                                     columns="2">                    

                    <apex:column headerValue="Name" >
                        <apex:outputField value="{!qs.Case_Result__c}"  rendered="{!(qs.Case_Result__c == 'Completed')}" />

                    </apex:column>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Class:

```
public class quicksls {
    public List<Quickcase__c> Quick {get;set;}
    public quicksls(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {}
    public void init() {
        Quick = [select id ,Name,Case_Result__c from Quickcase__c limit 50];
    }        
}
```

Comment: What does this post have to do with Salesforce1?

Comment: Hi Niranjan, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Please do not ask multiple questions about an identical issue. If you want to further clarify, **[edit]** your question to be more clear. There is a link to do this below each post you write. I have deleted your duplicate post *this time* but please refrain from such behavior moving forward.

Comment: ok soory sir....

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, I have used `Account` object and used `Industry` as a picklist and value as a `Agriculture`. So, you will see `industry` value if agriculture is there.

**Visualforce page :**

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account" extensions="quicksls" action="{!init}">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:outputPanel id="dynamicTablePanel">
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="dynamicTable" value="{!Account}" var="ac" columns="2">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name" >
                        <apex:outputField value="{!ac.Name}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Industry" >
                        <apex:outputField value="{!ac.Industry}" rendered="{!ac.Industry == 'Agriculture'}" />
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Class :**

```
public class quicksls {
    public List<Account> Account {get;set;}

    public quicksls(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {}

    public void init() {
        Account = [select id, Name, Industry from Account limit 50];
    }
}
```

[image]

Hope it helps